# Selecting missing entries in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table of people:

```
person_id | name
1         | bob
2         | jane
```

A table of questions they can answer:

```
qu_id | question
1     | How old are you?
2     | How tall are you?
```

And a table of answers:

```
answer_id | qu_id | person_id | answer
10        | 1     | 2         | 24
```

**What query will return a list of people and questions that have not been answered:**

For example, Unanswered questions:

```
qu_id | person_id
1     | 1
2     | 1
2     | 2
```

(I am using SQL Server Express 2012)

Comment: I think output is wrong. As per your scenario only person_id no 2 has given answer to question 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.qu_ID, a.person_ID
FROM    people a
        CROSS JOIN question b
        LEFT JOIN answer c
            ON  a.person_ID = c.person_ID AND
                b.qu_ID = c.qu_id
WHERE   c.person_ID IS NULL
ORDER   BY b.qu_id, a.person_id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f36d0/1)

RESULT

```
╔═══════╦═══════════╗
║ QU_ID ║ PERSON_ID ║
╠═══════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║         1 ║
║     2 ║         1 ║
║     2 ║         2 ║
╚═══════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: I think you mean `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`

Comment: @lc. right, i pasted the wrong data on the fiddle, instead of the answer table, i posted the desired result.

Comment: I like this answer because I can reference more columns in the main `SELECT` if I need to. Using `EXCEPT` doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT p.person_id, q.qu_id
FROM Person p
CROSS JOIN Question q

EXCEPT

SELECT person_id, qu_id
FROM Answers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT q.qu_id, p.person_id
FROM people AS p
CROSS JOIN questions AS q
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM answers AS a 
    WHERE a.qu_id = q.qu_id 
    AND a.person_id = p.person_id
)
```

Or,

```
SELECT q.qu_id, p.person_id
FROM people AS p
CROSS JOIN questions AS q
EXCEPT
SELECT qu_id, person_id
FROM answers
```